# Add amount of blank rows based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, cells

As the majority of those seeking aid here I am new to VBA, but I figured there is no way to solve my problem with conventional formulas hence the explanation:

I have several sets of materiel codes in col. A sorted from smallest to largest, their corresponding data in columns B to Y. What I need is add an amount of blank rows below every set of codes equalling the corresponding value in col. Z, below is an example of "before"

```
 - Col. A   ----  Col. Z
 - 65504927 - 3
 - 65504927 - 3
 - 65504927 - 3
 - 65505044 - 1
 - 65505044 - 1
 - 65505044 - 1
 - 65505151 - 0
 - 65505151 - 0
 - 65505297 - 2
 - 65505297 - 2
```

and After -

```
- Col. A   ----  Col. Z
- 65504927 - 3
- 65504927 - 3
- 65504927 - 3
- "blank row"
- "blank row"
- "blank row"
- 65505044 - 1
- 65505044 - 1
- 65505044 - 1
- "blank row"
- 65505151 - 0
- 65505151 - 0
- 65505297 - 2
- 65505297 - 2
- "blank row"
- "blank row"
```

I found a suggestion for a similar problem in one of the posts here (it adds a single row after every set of data) but I can't yet grasp VB architecture enough to make alterations, so I'd greatly appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Post the code you found, and your best attempt (even if it's only a comment like "I think something needs to go here"), and you'll get help. SO isn't a code writing service, and most people won't just do it for you.

Comment: Welcome to VBA coding. Here are some sites to get you started : [Welcome to the Visual Basic for Applications language reference for Office 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383.aspx), to skip the theories - [Visual Basic language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj692818.aspx)

Comment: And [Welcome to the Excel 2013 developer reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861528.aspx)

Comment: @chiv I am assuming that neither I nor Jeanno  answered your question completly becuase you haven't maked neither answer as correct. If we are slightly off give us more information and we will improve upon the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for me:

```
Sub add_blank_rows()
    Dim Awsh      As Worksheet
    Dim ARow      As Range
    Dim AColumn   As Range
    Dim UsedRange As Range
    Dim to_insert As Integer
    Dim count     As Integer

    Set Awsh = ActiveSheet
    Set UsedRange = Awsh.UsedRange
    Set AColumn = Range(Cells(1, 26), Cells(UsedRange.End(xlDown).Row, 26))

    For Each ARow In AColumn
        If Not ARow.Offset(1, 0) = ARow And _
           IsNumeric(ARow.Offset(1, 0)) And _
           IsNumeric(ARow) Then

            to_insert = ARow

            For count = 1 To to_insert
                ARow.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            Next count
        End If
    Next ARow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to determine which is the last row containing a unique value because after this row is when blanks are inserted. I have added an extra column "C" to indicate whether the row is the last one.

```
Sub AssignLast()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If i = 1 Then
            If Range("A" & i).Value <> Range("A" & i + 1).Value Then
                Range("C" & i).Value = 1
            End If
        Else
            If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value And _
                Range("A" & i).Value <> Range("A" & i + 1).Value Then
                    Range("C" & i).Value = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub InsertBlankRows()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("C" & i).Value = 1 Then
            Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + Range("B" & i).Value).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your help, you've got an awesome and helpful community here!

Special thanks to @sgp667, this worked like a charm:

```
Sub add_blank_rows()
Dim Awsh      As Worksheet
Dim ARow      As Range
Dim AColumn   As Range
Dim UsedRange As Range
Dim to_insert As Integer
Dim count     As Integer

Set Awsh = ActiveSheet
Set UsedRange = Awsh.UsedRange
Set AColumn = Range(Cells(1, 26), Cells(UsedRange.End(xlDown).Row, 26))

For Each ARow In AColumn
    If Not ARow.Offset(1, 0) = ARow And _
       IsNumeric(ARow.Offset(1, 0)) And _
       IsNumeric(ARow) Then

        to_insert = ARow

        For count = 1 To to_insert
            ARow.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        Next count
    End If
Next ARow
```

End Sub

Cheers!